# Showing a JLabel

Tags: java, swing

I want show on concerned cases (row 2 from the grid), my JLabel contained in my Pawn class.

```
if(i==1 && (j>-1 && j<8)) { new Pawn(colorr); }
```

generate the Pawn but on the grid, the JLabel named 'label' isn't showed.

**EDIT:I** *corrected some things like the container usage but my problem about my JLabel showing and to move my Pawn piece is still here.*

I would also enjoy to move later the Pawn to another position on the grid.

```
package coordboutons;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class CoordBoutons extends JFrame {
JFrame frame;
private Color colorr=Color.RED;
//private Container[][] cp=new Container[8][8];  
CoordBoutons() {
    super("GridLayout");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Container contenant = getContentPane();
    contenant.setLayout(new GridLayout(8, 8));

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            contenant.add(new CaseEchiquier(i, j));
        }
    }

    pack();
    setVisible(true);
}

class CaseEchiquier extends JPanel {

    private int lin, col;
    protected Color color;


    CaseEchiquier(int i, int j) {
        lin = i;
        col = j;
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80, 75));
        setBackground((i + j) % 2 == 0 ? Color.WHITE : Color.GRAY);
        if(i==1 && (j>-1 && j<8)) { new Pawn(colorr); }       
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {


            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
                CaseEchiquier current =(CaseEchiquier)e.getSource(); // get the object that the user pressed
               // int linX = current.getLin();
               // int colY = current.getCol();
                System.out.println(lin+"   "+col);

            }



        });

    }
    public int getCol() {
        return col;
    }

    public int getLin() {
        return lin;
    }

}

public class ChessPiece
{
    Color color;
    JLabel label;

}

public class Pawn extends ChessPiece
{
    public Pawn(Color c)
    {
        this.color = c;
        setBackground(colorr);
        System.out.println("YATAAA !");
        this.label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("bp.png"));
        //I need to show this label !;

    }

    public Color getColor()
    {
        return this.color;
    }

}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
            CoordBoutons coordBoutons = new CoordBoutons();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: Please clarify for us just what your question is.

Comment: And why are you having each cell in your 8 x 8 grid use a `GridLayout(8, 8)`? Shouldn't it be only the container that holds these cells that should be using this layout?

Comment: I corrected the problem about container and 8x8. Can you look for my problem please ? Thanks dude.

Comment: You're not adding a JLabel to any container, so it makes sense that it's not showing.

Comment: Having only glanced over the code, I think you tightly coupling render output with your model.  Basically, the board (in fact each cell) should know how to render it's content (this mean every possible piece).  The model should be providing feedback to the view as to what should be rendered where.  The view would then provide feedback to the model about moves that the user wants to make and validate those moves based on what the model sees as the current state of play, the piece in question and the rules in use...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to point out two major problems I saw in your code (there can be more :))

1. In your `CoordButtons` constructor you are doing the same thing 64
   times. According to what I understood you want to create a grid of
   8x8. So set the content pane layout to a 8x8 grid and add panels to
   it.

   ```
    CoordBoutons() {
          super("GridLayout");
          setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);     
          getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(8, 8));
          for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
               for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                  getContentPane().add(new CaseEchiquier(i, j));
               }
           }
           pack();
           setVisible(true);
    }
   ```
2. In your `CaseEchiquier` class just creating a `Pawn` object will
   not help you to display it. Instead add the label of `Pawn` object to
   your `JPanel`

   ```
      if(i==1 && (j>-1 && j<8)) { 
       Pawn p = new Pawn(colorr);
       add(p.label);
      }
   ```